# How can I extend a basis to a given spanned space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've seen many questions about extending bases, but I still don't get the idea of extending them to a space that is NOT `R4, ...` etc. Here's the question:

U, W are strict-subspaces of F4.

U=span{(1,0,1,1)transpose, (2,1,-1,-3)transpose}.

W=span{(4,1,1,-1)transpose, (0,1,2,1)transpose, (1,3,-3,-8)transpose}.

Find the basis of W including (1,0,1,1)transpose and (2,1,-1,-3)transpose.

I've shown that U< W...

any help please?

Comment: "Find **the** basis of $W$ including..."  There are uncountably infinitely many bases for $W$ including the two given vectors.  If you have shown that $U$ is a subspace of $W$, then since $U$ is currently dimension $2$ and $W$ is dimension $3$, literally pick **any** vector from $W$ which is not from $U$ (*check to make sure that your chosen vector is linearly independent from the two given vectors from $U$*) and this will be fine as a choice for how to extend the basis to $W$.

Comment: Although you could pick *any* vector from $W$ such that it isn't from $U$, and there are uncountably infinitely many such valid correct choices, there is little reason to look very hard or very far since you are told three vectors from $W$ in the first place and at most two of them could be elements of $U$ implying at least one of them is not an element of $U$ (*possibly even all three*).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So what you mean is to determine if either (4,1,1,-1) or (0,1,2,1) or (1,3,-3,-8) can be linearly independent with the vectors from U.
@JMoravitz

Comment: That is likely the intended solution and will lead you to a correct answer, but is by no means the only solution nor is it the only correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $U=span\{u_1, u_2\}$, $W=span\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$. All vectors are column vectors.

Then you can write a matrix which includes the basis for $U+W$, like this:
$$M = [u_1,u_2,w_1,w_2,w_3]$$

Then use Gaussian elimination on M to get an upper triangular matrix, which might be like:
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

In this case you can just add $w_2$ to $u_1,u_2$ to form your desired basis.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

In this case you can add $w_1, w_2$ or $w_3$.

Since Gaussian elimination starts from the upper left, it will always keep $u_1, u_2$ if they are linearly independent. And it shows clearly which vectors are linearly independent with respect to them. From the matrix we also see that $dim(U+W)=3$, which indicates $U\subset W$.

Comment: You mean making the reduced row echelon form? But in that case, I believe the third column has to be (2 1 0 0) transpose, and the fifth column (-3 2 1 0) How did you get the upper triangular matrix?

Comment: That's just an example. I didn't do the exact calculation.

Comment: Gaussian elimination does not change the linear independence of column vectors, so it will help you find the first three linear independent colomn vectors.